# Vertical Align Content Of Div To Bottom With Scroll Bar For Overflow

Tags: html, css, scroll, height, vertical-alignment

I have variable-height content in a fixed position div. In my case, it's a table, which gets rows added to it. I need it lined it up at the bottom of the div, which I accomplished by making the content position absolute bottom 0.

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>BlahBlahBlah</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Add more rows here. -->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

#outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 64px;
  right: 64px;
  bottom: 128px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
}

#inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  bottom: 16px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  /**
  This aligns content to the bottom,
  but there's never a scrollbar.*/
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2g1kLd5g/

If I add content, it remains lined up at the bottom, however eventually the content becomes taller than the div. In this case, the new content overflows past the top of the div and can't be seen.

http://jsfiddle.net/rs7ewqdu/

Therefore, I would like a scrollbar so the user can scroll up to see the hidden content. If I remove the absolute positioning and leave the overflow-y auto on the parent div, then I have a scrollbar, however it then always starts at the top position and must be scrolled down every time the page is loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/oncqwq9o/

That could (not ideally) be solved with a JavaScript auto-scroll. However, the real issue here is that if I make the content shorter, it now no longer lines up at the bottom of the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/1wnqbgbo/

```
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  bottom: 16px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Vertical-align doesn't appear to have any effect and I tried display:table-cell and display:block. The only way I have found to get the alignment I want is with position absolute, and when I do that there is no scrollbar.

Does anyone know how I can get the bottom of the content to line up with the bottom of the div by default, and have a scrollbar to handle the overflow? I would prefer a pure CSS solution if one exists.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? If so, could you post it?

Comment: No I didn't. Presently I have the scrolling turn on and off. But maybe you just try an upside down font and turn the monitor upside down.